# gpg2 exports invalid private key

Tags: ssh, gpg

I need to export both ssh keys from my gpg authentication subkey

First I get the fingerprint from my [A] authentication subkey:

```
gpg --list-secret-keys --with-keygrip
```

Having the fingerprint *15EDA5801C8D18FF*, I proceed:

```
public=/tmp/id_rsa.pub
private=/tmp/id_rsa
rm -f $public $private
gpg2 --armor --export-secret-subkeys 15EDA5801C8D18FF > $private
chmod 400 $private
ssh-keygen -y -e -f $private > $public
```

Both produced key files look fine to me, yet the code above returns

```
Load key "/tmp/id_rsa": invalid format
```

Comment: Why are you expecting `ssh-keygen` to understand a GnuPG key? (note that this may just be me not understanding things, but still)

Comment: If you just need the public key, then `ssh-add` will list it if you use gpg-agent as ssh-agent.

Comment: Here there is a good guide: https://opensource.com/article/19/4/gpg-subkeys-ssh